# передача переменной из iclude который подключен по url

Tags: php, переменные, include

У меня есть вот такой вот код:

```
  $login = $_POST["login"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];
  include "http://url/forum/XenForo.php?login=$login&password=$password";
  echo $success;
```

Он подключается к файлу который проверяет авторизован ли пользователь вот код на проверку авторизации в XenForo

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
// Verify login and password
$login = $_GET['login'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
if(empty($login) || empty($password)) {
    exit('Empty login or password');
}
// Load XenForo core
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$libraryDir = $dir . '/library';
require_once($dir . '/library/XenForo/Autoloader.php');
XenForo_Autoloader::getInstance()->setupAutoloader($libraryDir);
XenForo_Application::initialize($libraryDir, $dir);
XenForo_Application::set('page_start_time', microtime(true));
$db = XenForo_Application::get('db');
// Resolve user_id by login
$result = $db->fetchRow('SELECT user_id, username FROM xf_user WHERE username=' . $db->quote($login) . ' OR email=' . $db->quote($login));
if(!count($result)) {
    exit('Incorrect login');
}
$user_id = $result['user_id'];
$username = $result['username'];
// Get user data
$result = $db->fetchCol('SELECT data FROM xf_user_authenticate WHERE user_id=' . $db->quote($user_id));
if(!count($result)) {
    exit('Unable to get user data: ' . $user_id);
}
$data = $result[0];
// Select authentication core
$auth = NULL;
if(class_exists('XenForo_Authentication_Core12')) {
    $auth = new XenForo_Authentication_Core12;
} else if(class_exists('XenForo_Authentication_Core')) {
    $auth = new XenForo_Authentication_Core;
} else exit('Unable to select authentication core');
// Try authenticate
$auth->setData($data);
$success = $auth->authenticate($user_id, $password);
echo($success ? 'OK:' . $username : 'Incorrect login or password');
?>
```

Работает он великолепно.

Вопрос в следующем как мне передать в код выше результат авторизации из кода ниже.
При попытки получить данные из $success выводит следующее:

> OK:Wolfys Notice: Undefined variable: success in
>   /home/web/moderator/suscess.php on line 23

За ранние спасибо за помощь.
Указывать приходится только через URL так-как форум находится на другом под домене в отличии от микро сайта.

Comment: `$RESULT = file_get_contents("http://url/forum/XenForo.php?login=$login&password=$password");` и в `$RESULT` будет ваш ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое это мне помогло)